# Get first unique records from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA (
fieldA VARCHAR(2) ,
fieldB  VARCHAR(2),
fieldC VARCHAR(2),
fieldD VARCHAR(2),
DATE_PROD VARCHAR(8),
DATE_LOAD VARCHAR(8)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO TABLEA
(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD, DATE_PROD, DATE_LOAD)
VALUES
('1', '2', '3', '4', '10102015', '10112015'),
('1', '2', '3', '4', '11102015', '11102015'),
('1', '2', '3', '4', '11102015', '12102015'),
('2', '4', '3', '4', '11102015', '11102015')
;
```

I want a query that will get me just the unique fieldA through fieldD with the least DATE_PROD value and it's corresponding DATE_LOAD value

```
fieldA fieldB fieldC fieldD DATE_PROD DATE_LOAD
------ ------ ------ ------ --------- --------
1      2       3     4     10102015    10112015
2      4       3     4     11102015    11102015
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I greatly appreciate your gesture to provide DDL and DMLs .

You may use `KEEP .. DENSE_RANK .. FIRST`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23667/3)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT fieldA
    ,fieldB
    ,fieldC
    ,fieldD
    ,MIN(DATE_PROD) DATE_PROD
    ,MIN(DATE_LOAD) KEEP (
        DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DATE_PROD
        ) DATE_LOAD
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY fieldA
    ,fieldB
    ,fieldC
    ,fieldD
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23667/3/0)**:

```
| FIELDA | FIELDB | FIELDC | FIELDD | DATE_PROD | DATE_LOAD |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|-----------|-----------|
|      1 |      2 |      3 |      4 |  10102015 |  10112015 |
|      2 |      4 |      3 |      4 |  11102015 |  11102015 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD, DATE_PROD, DATE_LOAD
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD
            ORDER BY DATE_PROD) rn
    FROM yourTable t
) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

I am assuming that there are no ties for the earliest production date, or, if there are, you don't care which single record gets returned.  If you want to include ties, then we can use a rank function instead of row number.

Also, consider storing your date information using a date type rather than as text.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tablea o
where exists(
            Select 1 from (
                            Select fielda, min(date_prod) as date_prod
                            from tablea
                            group by fielda
                          ) i
            Where i.fielda = o.fielda
            and i.date_prod = o.date_prod
            )
;
```

It will solve your purpose...